# How to get the encoding of a file in a repository git via C#?

Tags: c#, git

Does anyone know a way to retrieve the encoding of files that are stored in a git repository in C#? I try to retrieve the content via the URL with a `WebClient` and retrieve the contents of the file with `DownloadString` method, but it does not really suit what I want. It returns the content of the HTML page with the doctype so its encoding is not the encoding of the file stored, but that of the html file.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 try
 {
   client.DownloadString(filename);
 }
 catch (webexception we)
 {
    logger.writelinelog(we.message + "\n" + we.status.tostring());
 }
```

Comment: What provider are you hosting the git repository on? github?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right URL? For example on Github you can either [view a code file embedded within a HTML page](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/scripts/lib/archive.js) or you can [access the raw file itself](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/master/scripts/lib/archive.js). The "raw" link just downloads the file content and does not contain any HTML in the response. You didn't mention what repository you're trying to fetch data from, of course, but that's just an example of a potential issue.

Comment: I am in Azure DevOps, The URL is right, i have somthing like this:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    
    

<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>
 
            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In
        
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />

Comment: The presence of the words "Sign In" in that URL would suggest to me that your request was not authenticated, and you were redirected to the sign-in or home page. DevOps repos are not usually public, so a bog-standard HTTP request to the file will not work. You'd need to provide appropriate credentials. Or is the repo actually public? Does the rest of the code file appear below that sample HTML you gave, or not? I can't see any way, through the web GUI, to get the raw content of a file, unless you can figure out the correct "download" URL for your file.

Comment: If this repo is public, can you tell us the URL you are trying to visit?

Comment: P.S. Since it's git, to be honest it's probably easier to clone (part of) the repo to your disk and look at it that way. You'd need the same credentials (if any) either way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the correct answer to "how to find the encoding of a file" is "you can't, you'll have to guess". You have accepted your own answer, and it's good you found something that solved your problem, but there is no 100% way of determining the encoding of an arbitrary text file. Yes, there are byte order marks for a few encodings, but the rest - it's a guess. You should point that out in your answer, as future visitors might take your answer at face value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,
I can find the solution:
Since it's a matter of simply checking whether the stored procedure is in UTF-8 or not in my case I proceeded as follows
In C #: we can detect the types of encoding UTF 8 BOM from the stream, for the UTF8 I have a special characters check in the stream (to improve) and all that does not fit in this case are not not UTF- 8

Thank you so much for your help.

```
public static Encoding GetFileEncoding(GitRepository repository, GitItem gitItem)
    {
        GitVersionDescriptor versionDesc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.Branch) ? new GitVersionDescriptor()
        {
            VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
            Version = Configuration.Branch,
            VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
        } : null;

        using (Stream stream = GitClient.GetItemContentAsync(repository.Id, gitItem.Path, download: false, versionDescriptor: versionDesc, includeContentMetadata: true, includeContent: true).Result)
        {
            var bom = new byte[4];
            stream.Read(bom, 0, 4);
            // Analyze the BOM
            if (bom[0] == 0x2b && bom[1] == 0x2f && bom[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7;
            if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8;
            if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode; //UTF-16LE
            if (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; //UTF-16BE
            if (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff) return Encoding.UTF32;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, true))
            {
                reader.Peek();
                if (reader.ReadToEnd().Contains('�'))
                {
                    return Encoding.ASCII;
                }
                return Encoding.UTF8;
            }
        }
```

Comment: **Warning** for future visitors. Note that there is **no** way to 100% determine the encoding of an arbitrary text file. Some byte order marks exists, like shown in the answer, that identifies a few encodings (that is, they reduce the chance that the guess is wrong to almost zero - but not altogether zero), but for the rest it is a guess. It may be that you have a corpus you know the *set of encodings* for so the above code would be good enough, but to determine the encoding of an arbitrary text file, it will be a guess, which may be wrong. You have been warned.